# ubuntu apt-add-repository showing error

Tags: python, ubuntu

when i tried this command

```
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jd-team/jdownloader
```

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-add-repository", line 22, in <module>
    sys.stdout.detach(), encoding="UTF-8", line_buffering=True)
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'detach'
```

please help me to remove this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are somehow using python2 to run `/usr/bin/apt-add-repository`, you either need to change the shebang to `#! /usr/bin/python3` or you have changed what python3 points to. Running `head -n 1 /usr/bin/apt-add-repository` will show you what the shebang is currently set to.